# template function auto return type with std::conditional

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming, rvalue-reference

I would like to write a generic function that could take either

(1) a rvalue reference of A and return a move-constructed type B:

```
A a;
B b = f(std::move(A));
// use b normally and a is now empty.
```

or
(2) a lvalue reference of A and return a wrapper object that wraps A from automatic type deduction:

```
A a;
auto b = f(A);
// a could be used normally. The type of b is of a very complex form deduced based on the implementation of f()
B bb = b.eval(); // use eval() method from the auto type to make an evaluation of the wrapper object b to effectively copy-construct bb from a.
```

I am able to do this by doing the following:

```
template <typename T>
auto f(T&& t)
 -> typename std::conditional
          <!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value,
           T,
           decltype (t.sqrt() + (t * 2).sin())  // ideally this could be decltype(auto) to not repeat the code but this is not allowed by C++
          >::type
{
    T _t(std::forward<T>(t));
    return _t.sqrt() + (_t * 2).sin()  // T is a data type of some template expression library with lazy evaluation capability, e.g., Eigen::Matrix, hence this line will return an expression type that is composed from the types involved in the expression, i.e. sqrt, +, *, sin. 
 }
```

My question is, as pointed out in the comments of the code above, how to remove that repeating of computation in the `decltype()` call without using `decltype(auto)` as `auto` keyword is prohibited in template parameter of `std::conditional`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no repeating computation, just code duplication. Code duplication can be avoided using a function.

```
template <typename T>
auto f(T&& t)
 -> typename std::conditional
          <!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value,
           T,
           decltype (function(t))
          >::type
{
    T _t(std::forward<T>(t));
    return function(_t);
}
```